# How can i pass simple data (json) from angular2 final(2.0.1)

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio-2015, angular2-directives

this code it's work on Angular2 2.0.0.rc.2 but now it's did't work
Error. import FORM_DIRECTIVES ,HTTP_PROVIDERS ,bootstrap

how to fix this to Angular2 v2.0.1

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response, URLSearchParams} from "@angular/http";
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from "@angular/common"    //error
```

can't import FORM_DIRECTIVES in Angular v2.0.1

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { IFood} from "./food";
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/Rx";

@Component({

selector: "my-app",
directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],   //error
templateUrl: "./app/form.html"
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
public values: string[];
public headers: Headers;
errorMessage: string;
foods: IFood[];
foodModel = <IFood>{}; 

constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
}

ngOnInit() {
    return this.http.get("/home/getdata")
        .map((response: Response) => <IFood[]>response.json())
        .subscribe(data => this.foods = data, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
onSubmit(form): void {
    let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }); 
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log(this.foodModel);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.foodModel));

    this.http.post("/home/postform", JSON.stringify(this.foodModel), options)
        .map((response: Response) => <IFood>response.json())
        .subscribe(json => { alert(this.foodModel.foodId +"  "+ this.foodModel.foodName); /* handle it */ });
}
```

and in main.ts

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

can't import bootsrap

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';   //error http_providers
```

can't import HTTP_PROVIDERS
    bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);      //error bootstrap

how to fix this to Angular2 v2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `NgModule`s
See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html for detaisl

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, ReativeFormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

and change the bootstrapping code

```
// The browser platform with a compiler
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

// The app module
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

// Compile and launch the module
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: I'm have this in my project but when i changing angular2 version some command does't work.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with "some commands don't work". What commands? What error messages do you get? What Angular2 version changed you to?

Comment: in app.component.ts
can't
     import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from "@angular/common" 
and can't use directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],

Comment: `FORM_DIRECTIVES` or other `xxx_DIRECTIVES` or `xxx_PIPES` or `xxx_PROVIDERS` don't exist anymore. You need to import `XxxModule` instead as shown in my answer. Please read the docs I linked to.

Comment: How can i pass data from controller to front-end angular 2 final

Comment: Can you please create a new question with the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish?